# X-axis doesn't scale correctly?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Here is my code snippet:

```
fig = px.line(df, x="epoch_time_ms", y="bacteria_count", line_shape="hv", markers=True, color='bacteria_type')
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
```

And my graph looks like this
[image]

The x-axis scale isn't correct.  For example, the time gap between first two data points is ~42 sec, and the time gap between 3rd and 4th is ~18 sec.  But you can see that distances between points don't really reflect it (i.e. I expect the distance between 3rd and 4th is like half of the distance between first 2 data points).

Is there a way to fix this scaling issue?

Thanks!

P.S.  I am on `dash 2.0` and `plotly 5.3.1`.

Comment: Is it better if I convert it to date/time format and then use this? `fig.update_xaxes(type='date')`

Comment: @r-beginners with `type='date'`, the x-axis will only show dates...all my data points are within 1 single day.  So all data points would be collapsed into just 1 dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have built a sample dataframe.  Both axis as time and epoch ms work.  Are you sure your epoch times are numbers not strings or objects (i.e. are being treated as a categorical rather that continuous series)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-nov-2021","2-nov-2021", freq="S")).sample(30),
             "bacteria_count":np.random.randint(0,500, 30), "bacteria_type":np.random.choice(list("AB"),30)})

df["epoch_time_ms"] = df["time"].astype(int) / 1000
df = df.sort_values("time")
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="bacteria_count", line_shape="hv", markers=True, color='bacteria_type')
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
fig.show()

fig = px.line(df, x="epoch_time_ms", y="bacteria_count", line_shape="hv", markers=True, color='bacteria_type')
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I found the issue -- I had this time to strip off the date component: `df['epoch_time_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['epoch_time_ms'], unit='ms').dt.time`.  It seems that dash plotly doesn't treat x-axis with just time component well.

Comment: it's pretty much as I stated,  objects become categorical not continuous axis. in this case python time is an object. hence given question answer is correct (you didn't provide sample data or code you were using)